# Plotting multivariate model in two dimenstion

Tags: r

Can anyone tell me how to plot  a multivariate model  with only one variable.

For example I want to predict Height of trees with explanatory variables  like Mean annual temperature and Mean annual precipitation.

My model for example can be a quadratic function like

```
Model<- lm( height~ poly(Mean Temp,2)+ poly(Mean ppt,2))
```

What I want is a plot which has only height and mean temperature.

Is it possible?

---

Thanks  The Kaspa
I think I need to re frame my question. What I want is to have a plot with the observed values of the mean_tem on x axis and Height on Y axis and **fitted line from the model containing both Temperature and PPT**. I know mathematically we can do it by decomposing the 2nd explanatory variable but I am not being able to do it I R.

Hope I made myself clear now
Thanks
Dev

Comment: Yes it is possible. What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.
You need to create a `Mean_temp` for the mean of temperature, but

```
Plot <- plot(Mean_Temp, height, data=Yourdata)
```

should work.